# Running Kubernetes on a single machine bare metal

Tags: kubernetes

I'm looking to run Kubernetes in production on a single machine - bare metal - no VM. But can't seem to find a writeup for this scenario. The reason is basically that we have on-premise small installations and we'd prefer to have everything based on Kubernetes rather than having two different environments - one cloud and one on-prem.

**Update**

With the official Ubuntu guide I managed to get it up and running in conjunction with the following: http://www.dangtrinh.com/2017/09/how-to-deploy-openstack-in-single.html. LXD version was wrong for what Conjure was expecting and IPv6 needs to be turned off for LXD. Now I am the happy owner of an Intel NUC here for testing which acts as a master and a node. Thanks for all the assistance in the comments!

Comment: Here is official [Kuebernetes on Ubuntu](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/) guide. This also support bare-metal installation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm slightly confused with the official guides. What I want to accomplish is a single machine acting as both a master and a node - this might be the trick. Just as MInikube does, but on bare metal. If that guide works, I'm home free. I've been barking up the tree of getting this onto CoreOS or CentOS. Total n00b in these things though..

Comment: Kubernetes is cloud-agnostic which means it does not matter if you run it on-premise or on cloud  as well as on bare metal or on VM. It should behave similarly.Therefore, you can use any writeup scenarios

Comment: @Einarl , If you want the single node to behave Master as well as Worker node, you need to make sure it's not tainted. By default, it's not allowed to deploy workloads on the master node.

Comment: Hope you found the solution. If not, check this out https://blog.tekspace.io/setup-kubernetes-cluster-with-ubuntu-16-04/